# How secure is base64 encoding in combination with lower case conversion for passwords?

Tags: mysql, encryption, base64

I'm currently working on a school-project and part of the task is to enable user login. Therefore I thought that using a simple base64 encoding with an conversion to lower case afterwards would be a pretty good encryption, because base64 normally consists of upper and lower characters. Here's a representational code:

```
set @passwd = 'Password';
set @salt = 'Salt';
set @email = 'tmp@gmail.com';

INSERT INTO `db_scrumboardtable`.`tb_user` (`mail`, `password`, `nameToDisplay`) VALUES (@email, LOWER(to_base64(sha2(concat(@passwd,@salt),512))) , 'test');

select u.tb_User_id from `db_scrumboardtable`.`tb_user` u where u.mail = @email and u.password = LOWER(to_base64(sha2(concat(@passwd,@salt),512)));
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Base64 can be reversed by anyone.  You might as well store it in plaintext.

Comment: In addition to the significant issues pointed out below, the correct usage would be `TO_BASE64(UNHEX(SHA2(...)))`.  The hash functions in MySQL return their values hex-encoded, which needs to be undone, otherwise you have a lot of wasted bits (effectively equivalent to 4:8), since you are providing twice as many bytes to base64 as are actually needed to convey the information, so only 3 bits per byte (of 6 possible, since there are 64 symbols) of your base64 result are meaningful.  This would further simplify reversing your "algorithm" because 240/256 possible inputs are invalid by definition.

Answer (score 7):

It's not secure and it's not encryption.

If you change all the base64-encoded chars to lower case, you'll lose the ability to get back the original value ("decrypt"). Since passwords should not be encrypted, but hashed, this is not so bad.

Now, thinking about why we're hashing passwords, the usual attack scenario is that an attacker successfully manages to steal the hashed password list, but in order to get those passwords they need to brute-force the input to find a match. In this case, they can simply decode the "encrypted" password and get a valid password out. Of course, this password has limited usefulness, because it can be used to log in to the server it was stolen from, but not necessarily to some other service the user might have used the same password for.

---

Passwords should be properly hashed with schemes like PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2 with high cost factor or many iterations.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't close to secure. Your injective transformation (mixed case to lower case) makes passwords easier to guess, not harder.

Please don't, in the 21st century riddled with cybercrooks, try to invent your own security software.  Please read this. http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php